# LogonUser fails with 1326 for local user

Tags: windows, authentication

I am logged onto my machine as a user with administrative privileges. I am trying run this small program :

```
bRetValue = LogonUser((LPTSTR)"user2local", L".", (LPTSTR)"Passw0rd", LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken);
lastError = GetLastError();
printf("Error Code: %d\n",lastError);
```

But for some reason the API returns error code 1326 - Unknown user name or bad password error code. The user exists on my machine and the password is also correct.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Those (LPTSTR) casts just stopped the compiler from telling you that you were doing it wrong, they did not stop you from doing it wrong.  Use wide character literals, like L"user2local" or use LogonUserA().

Comment: @HansPassant You are right. Using LogonUserA() worked. Changing the CharacterSet used by the project from Unicode to None also works if LogonUser is used.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html